# How to add an opening tag only to a HTML document in Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Im trying to make an automated script that will download a table from a website and then use regular expressions to take out the relevant data. The html is

```
<tr>
    <td class="data0"><b><a target="blank"  href="index.php?section=consegne_ucraina">UKRAINE</a></td>
    <td class="value0" style="font-style:italic;text-align:center">Jan-Feb 2016</td>
    <td class="value0" style="text-align:right"><small>(e)</small> 1.181</td>       
    <td class="value0" style="text-align:right;border-left:1px dotted"><i style="color:red">-12</i></td>
    <td class="value0" style="text-align:right"><i style="color:red">-1,0%</i></td>
    <td class="value0" style="text-align:right;border-left: dotted 1px"><i style="color:red">-71</i></td>
    <td class="value0" style="text-align:right"><i style="color:red">-5,7%</i></td>
    <td class="value0" style="text-align:right;border-left: dotted 1px"><i style="color:red">-42</i></td>
    <td class="value0" style="text-align:right"><i style="color:red">-3,4%</i></td>
</tr>

    <td class="data1"><a target="blank"  href="index.php?section=consegne">EU-28</a></td>
    <td class="value1" style="font-style:italic;text-align:center">Jan-Feb 2016</td>
    <td class="value1" style="text-align:right">25.045</td>     
    <td class="value1" style="text-align:right;border-left:1px dotted"><i style="color:green">+1.779</i></td>
    <td class="value1" style="text-align:right"><i style="color:green">+7,6%</i></td>
    <td class="value1" style="text-align:right;border-left: dotted 1px"><i style="color:green">+1.559</i></td>      
    <td class="value1" style="text-align:right"><i style="color:green">+6,6%</i></td>
    <td class="value1" style="text-align:right;border-left: dotted 1px"><i style="color:green">+2.743</i></td>
    <td class="value1" style="text-align:right"><i style="color:green">+12,3%</i></td>              
</tr>
```

So far my code can get out the first pat of the `<tr>`, including the first 3 values i.e. UKRAINE, Jan-Feb 2016 and 1.18. But as you can see due to an error on the html page there is not a opening `<tr>` tag on the next section which stops my program. Is there a way to insert just an opening `<tr>` tag in that location, At the moment I can only get BeautifulSoup to insert an opening and closing  tag around the `<a>` tag using this code.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage,'html.parser')
a= soup.find("a", attrs={"href":"index.php?section=consegne"})
tr = soup.new_tag('tr')
a_idx = a.parent.contents.index(a)
a.parent.insert(a_idx , tr)
```

This gives me the following

```
</tr>
<td class="data1"><tr></tr><a href="index.php?section=consegne" target="blank">EU-28</a></td>
```

So in conclusion I need someone to help me move only an opening `<tr>` tag outside the `<td>` tag and in failing that make only an opening `<tr>` tag and an opening `<td>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Molloy! What you can try to do instead is parse the HTML with regular expressions and urllib. The code would look something like this:

```
import urllib
import re
try: 
        url = ('url that youre trying to access')
        req = urllib.request.Request(url)
        resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        respData = resp.read()
    except (TimeoutError, urllib.error.URLError) as e:
        print(e)

    month = re.findall(r'<td class="value0" style="font-style:italic;text-align:center">(.*?)</td>', str(respData)) 
    number = re.findall(r'<td class="value0" style="text-align:right"><small>(e)</small>(.*?)</td>', str(respData))
```

You would have to repeat the search variables (i.e. re.findall) for all the data you're trying to find. 
Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help. the only problem is that unfortunately the html page has 2 tables with about 14 countries on each one and I'm not sure if the code changes or not. My code does work if I download the html and insert a `<tr>` manually, I'm just looking for a way to insert it before I try a different method.